# Redirect rule Apache multiple Custom post type to posts

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I read the related questions above but no answers...so here is my problem :

I recently created several custom post types . They are 13 of them located located in /news/ folder.
For some personal reasons, yesterday I decided not to use the Custom post type anymore and rather re-write all of them as a "usual post" in my WP blog.
So the 13 Custom PT are now duplicated.
I could have delete them but they are already indexed by Google and their URL's are already around on the web, so I want to maintain them for a while to be sure that I do not loose any traffic of course.

The problem is that this morning, Google web master tool did not like all these duplicated contents at all.

**I need to redirect all the 13 URL's to the new posts created.**
How can I redirect 13 URL's to 13 new URL's ? Is this rule enough ? Should I also mention not to follow the Custom Type URL ?

**Here is the construction of the URL's:**
CUSTOM POST TYPES :
www.mysite.com/myblog/news/custom-post-type-title/

URL OF THE NEW DUPLICATED ARTICLE :
www.mysite.com/myblog/post-type-title

Thank you in advance for your help,
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To tell Google about duplicates, use code 301 when redirecting with RewriteRule (add [R=301] at the end of it) to denote "Permanently moved" on all URLs except for the currently valid one.